# Which Template Page Should I Use?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, menus, archive-template

I have created several custom post types (for example: FAQs, products and case studies) and registered a global custom taxonomy for use across all CPTs. In my case this taxonomy is called *audiences*. These are listed as consumers, architects and merchants.

In this example I'll use FAQs in the Merchants taxonomy.

---

I'm struggling to figure out how to filter the FAQs to show for a specific audience. My `archive-faqs.php` lists all FAQs regardless of audience type.

I want to be able to show all the FAQs tagged as merchant. What are my options for this?

- Do I create a custom `page.php` template and create a custom loop for it?
- Do I some how amend my `archive-faqs.php` to grab a query string?
- Is there a better way for me to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could always make a custom wp_query and put it in a template-custom.php.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'faqs',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'audiences',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'merchants',
        )
    ),
) );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
    // Show Posts ...
       the_title();
endwhile;

/* Restore original Post Data  */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Yeah this is my fallback option. I'm sure I am just missing something though.

Comment: I've taken this route due to time constraints. I still have the feeling that it isn't best practise though.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm struggling to figure out how to filter the FAQs to show for a specific audience. My archive-faqs.php lists all FAQs regardless of audience type.

- So you have FAQs
- You have some FAQs appropriate for one audience
- Some appropriate for another audience

What if we grouped these FAQs by audience? Suddenly we have a **taxonomy** of FAQs, **FAQ Audience**

Now you have `archive-faqs.php` for listing FAQs, but you also have `taxonomy-audiences.php` for FAQs for a particular audience. Remember, the content determines the template, not the other way around. `archive-faq.php` doesn't make the page load FAQ's it's loading and archive of FAQ's that makes WP load `archive-faq.php`. **WP has already fetched all the posts by the time it decides which template to load.**

With that in mind, you already have an archive for displaying FAQs by the audience, probably at `example.com/audiences/audienceslug`

The template hierarchy suggests that the following templates are tested:

- taxonomy-audiences-audienceslug.php
- taxonomy-audiences.php
- taxonomy.php
- archive.php
- index.php

[See here for details on the taxonomy template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

### A Word From The Wise

It's very tempting to create page templates and other templates, then use `WP_Query` or `get_posts`. If you're a particularly awful person you might use `query_posts`.

This is wrong, if you want to change filter or adjust what posts the main query fetches from the database, use the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the query object. This way you can add arguments and remove them before it goes to the database.

Comment: I've got my taxonomy registered to multiple CPTs. If I do `taxonomy-audiences-audienceslug.php` I'm just going to pull in everything that has `audienceslug` regardless of if it is an FAQ or say a case study or news post. Or am I missing something?